# GCC and ld can't find exported symbols...but they're there

Tags: c++, linux, g++, shared-libraries

I have a C++ library and a C++ application trying to use functions and classes exported from the library. The library builds fine and the application compiles but fails to link. The errors I get follow this form:

> app-source-file.cpp:(.text+0x2fdb): undefined reference to `lib-namespace::GetStatusStr(int)'

Classes in the library seem to be resolved just fine by the linker, but free functions and exported data (like a cosine lookup table) invariably result in the above error.

I am using Ubuntu 8.04 (Hardy), and it is up to date with the latest Ubuntu packages.

The command to link the library is (with other libraries removed):

```
g++ -fPIC -Wall -O3 -shared -Wl,-soname,lib-in-question.so -o ~/project/lib/release/lib-in-question.so
```

The command to link the application is (with other libraries removed):

```
g++ -fPIC -Wall -O3  -L~/project/lib/release -llib-in-question -o ~/project/release/app-in-question
```

Finally, it appears (as best as I can tell) that the symbols in question are being exported properly:

```
nm -D ~/project/lib/release/lib-in-question.so | grep GetStatusStr --> U _ZN3lib-namespace12GetStatusStrEi
```

Comment: You are not giving us enough information; consequently you will be getting a lot of wrong guesses.  You probably just made a simple mistake.  Simplify the code needed to reproduce the error to a minimum.  Then post it along with the actual shell commands, and their output, which lead to the error.

Comment: "lib-namespace" is not a legal namespace, what's the actual symbol name?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the U before _ZN3lib-namespace12GetStatusStrEi in the nm output shows that the symbol is **undefined** in the library.

Maybe it's defined in the wrong namespace: it looks like you're calling it in lib-namepace but you might be defining it in another.

Comment: Any suggestion on how to get the symbol defined? The cpp file it lives in is definitely being compiled!

Comment: I just edited my answer: maybe you used it in the wrong namespace

Answer (score 2):

It's been a while, but if you specify a lib with the -l option, then don't you have the skip the lib prefix?

(I changed the name from "lib-in-question.so" to "libfoobar.so" for easier reading for the example below)

```
g++ -fPIC -Wall -O3  -L~/project/lib/release -lfoobar
```

or

```
g++ -fPIC -Wall -O3  ~/project/lib/release/libfoobar.so
```

Comment: My makefile has that bit right: the library is libzclocksupport but the linker command is -lzclocksupport