# linker tells me it can't resolve symbols, but they're there?

Tags: gcc, linker, shared-libraries, linker-errors

I am trying to compile a simple test app using a library I've written. This compiles and runs fine on other machines.

I have libroller.so available at /usr/lib. I'm compiling a main.cpp as such:

```
g++ -g3 -Wall -I"../../" -lrt -lroller -o rap main.o
```

It complains of numerous errors such as:

```
/....../main.cpp:51: undefined reference to `Log::i(char const*, ...)'
```

However, I know that these exist in this so:

```
nm -Ca /usr/lib/libroller.so | grep "Log::i"            
00000000001f5d50 T Log::i(char const*, ...)
0000000000149530 W Log::i(std::string const&)
```

Both are 64 bit:

```
file /usr/lib/libroller.so           
/usr/lib/libroller.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped

file main.o   
main.o: ELF 64-bit LSB relocatable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

Unlike [GCC and ld can't find exported symbols...but they're there!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216450/gcc-and-ld-cant-find-exported-symbols-but-theyre-there) I'm pretty sure these symbols are defined. The same .so works with another using some of the same symbols.

EDIT/ANSWER: The order of objects is important. Placing main.o before the libraries was necessary. I'm guessing the linker had no unresolved symbols to deal with until it got to main.o -- which was the last object in its list. I'm still a little confused as to why this worked on other machines for many months...

Comment: Your question is a dup of [this one][1], and has the same answer.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380087/boost-1-48-linking-issue-with-gcc-4-6-1

Comment: Thanks. I did search, I promise :) Searching for "unresolved" and "gcc" turn up LOTS of irrelevant answers...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change:

```
g++ -g3 -Wall -I"../../" -lrt -lroller -o rap main.o
```

to:

```
g++ -g3 -Wall main.o -lroller -lrt -o rap
```

Link order matters (and the `-I` is redundant in this instance).

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing the sequence of library and main.o:

`g++ -g3 -Wall -I"../../" -o rap main.o  -lrt -lroller`

Have a look at this post: [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/linker-order-gcc)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a dup of [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8380087/boost-1-48-linking-issue-with-gcc-4-6-1), and has the same answer: order of libraries on link line [matters](http://webpages.charter.net/ppluzhnikov/linker.html).