# SDL2 - Undefined references - Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, reference, sdl, undefined

I just started using SDL2 (on Ubuntu 13.04 x64) and everything was going fine, until I tried to use SDL_image.

I added this piece of code, for loading images:

```
SDL_Texture* LoadImage(std::string file)
{
    SDL_Texture* tex = NULL;
    tex = IMG_LoadTexture(ren, file.c_str());
    if (tex == NULL)
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to load image: " + file + IMG_GetError());
    return tex;
}
```

I link with -lSDL2 and -lSDL2_image, and I get this undefined references:

```
g++  -o "SDL"  ./src/main.o   -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image.so: riferimento non definito a "SDL_malloc"
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image.so: riferimento non definito a "SDL_memcmp"
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image.so: riferimento non definito a "SDL_strncasecmp"
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image.so: riferimento non definito a "SDL_memset"
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image.so: riferimento non definito a "SDL_free"
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image.so: riferimento non definito a "SDL_memcpy"
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image.so: riferimento non definito a "SDL_sscanf"
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image.so: riferimento non definito a "SDL_isspace"
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image.so: riferimento non definito a "SDL_realloc"
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image.so: riferimento non definito a "SDL_strcmp"
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image.so: riferimento non definito a "SDL_strncmp"
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/libSDL2_image.so: riferimento non definito a "SDL_snprintf"
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: Just in case, wouldn't this be a Question for [ubuntu.se]?

Comment: I was actually not sure if the problem is Ubuntu-related or if I'm not linking correctly, or something like that.

Comment: Me neither, it's not my area of work. Check their [help center](http://askubuntu.com/help) and/or research the site.

Answer (score 2):

It's possible that changing the order of the libraries will solve the problem.

```
g++  -o "SDL"  ./src/main.o -lSDL2_image -lSDL2
```

Ref: [linker tells me it can't resolve symbols, but they're there?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8382153/linker-tells-me-it-cant-resolve-symbols-but-theyre-there)

Answer (score 1):

Have you downloaded and compiled/installed the libraries? 
Try this:

```
sudo apt-get install libsdl-dev
```

After that you can compile and link against SDL with:

```
gcc `pkg-config --libs --cflags sdl` <sourcefile.c>
```

Comment: Thanks fo the answer! ...I compiled the libraries...libsdl-dev is already installed, and it would install version 1.2 anyways